# Android Memory Leak - Anonymous class

Tags: android, memory-leaks

will the below code will cause memory leak?
Assume the method is in Activity

```
        public void main(){
        final Object obj = new Object();
        Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.sleep(25000);//sleep
                obj.hashCode();//do something
            }
        };
          new Thread(run).start();
    }
```

Does this lead to leak? Since the thread refer the Object which is created outside it

Thanks
Ram

Comment: this would not even compile ... you cannot assign to final again (not mentioning about lack of method in Runnable implementation and missig semicolon)

Comment: why you have to do this ? why not put it in onDestroy()

Comment: Sorry for incorrect syntax. If the background thread still waiting after activity destroy and now how does it behave. (I know if the Object is member of class then the activity leak for sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, threads don't follow the Activity lifecycle, so if you create a thread and the Runnable is an anonymous class it will have an implicit reference to the Activity because java will create an inner class.

If the Activity orientation changes or any other type of configuration changes Android will destroy the Activity and create a new one, however, it can't be deallocated by the garbage collector because threads are considered GC roots, the net effect is that you will have 2 activities in memory until your thread ends. If your thread ends before a configuration change you're ok, but this is not recommended practice since you usually can't guarantee that.

A solution would be to declare the runnable as an inner static class or an external class, and when a configuration change happens any reference to the activity that you have in the Thread/Runnable you pass the reference of the new activity.